# How do I print out 2d list elements with line spaced?

Tags: python

```
l = [[True, False, False, False, False], [True, False, False, False, False],
     [True, False, False, False, False], [True, False, False, False, False], 
     [True, False, False, False, False]]

for i in l:
    for j in i:
        if j == False:
            print ("-", end = '')
        else:
            print ("#", end = '')
```

This is my code and it prints out

```
#----#----#----#----#----
```

However, I want it to print out with the line spaced from the list, like this

```
#----
#----
#----
#----
#----
```

How would I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Add a `print()` at the end of the loop to print a newline after each row.

```
l = [[True, False, False, False, False], [True, False, False, False, False],
     [True, False, False, False, False], [True, False, False, False, False], 
     [True, False, False, False, False]]

for i in l:
    for j in i:
        if j == False:
            print ("-", end = '')
        else:
            print ("#", end = '')
    print()
```

Answer (score 0):

Just print after each item in l:

```
for i in l:
    for j in i:
        if j == False:
            print ("-", end = '')
        else:
            print ("#", end = '')
    print()
```